# Being notified when user turns on location services iOS 7 and up

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8, core-location, cllocationmanager

I am faced with a situation where we would like to kick off a particular process based on whether or not a user has locations services enabled or not. This part is trivial. However, we want to extend this functionality by changing our process if the user turns the locations services off or on. We currently are able to monitor, and change or process, when the user turns off location services. My question is, how can our app be notified when the user turns locations services back on?

Here is what we are currently working with

- iOS 7
- Background Location Mode is enabled
- We are using request always for location services

Here is what we tried

1. We have tried setting a timer after a user turns off the location service to periodically check if the user turns back on the location service. This is less than desirable for many reasons. Besides that the timer is killed once location services is turned off because background services is no longer needed and the OS kills our process. This is understandable.
2. We also went the approach of notifying the user that they just stopped a process and they need to turn location services back on. There are two problems with this approach.

   1. If the user does not have notifications enabled then this approach is no good at all.
   2. If they do have notifications enable then we first need the user to turn the location services back on and then they would need to open the app back up to get our app to "wake" back up.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I heard that some apps to keep live in background use other background modes (e.g. Playing and Recording Background Audio). If app will work you can use timer for checking location service state. But, if location manager create in background it will live only 180 secs(in this case you need working with location manager zones(create and recreate their)). But you have to explain to apple why your app using other background modes

Comment: @gaRik Clever, one thing we will try is using the background fetch mode and instead of doing a fetch we will just check location enabled. This might be a problem with Apple though...

Comment: background fetch works occasionally and few times per day and and at random times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of research and implement trying to  a solution we have discovered that this is not possible as of iOS 8. For reference here is what we found:

1. We were able to be notified when the user had shut off the location services, **ONLY** if they shut off location services to our app. We did not receive a notification if the user shut off the main location services.
2. We **did not** receive a message if the locations services was turned back on, regardless, if it was our location service or the main location service.
3. You cannot use a timer approach because the timer is killed if the app is sent to background. So we could not have periodically checked. *This would not have been acceptable for our use case but it was worth entertaining*
4. You can still call CLLocationManager as if you had permission to use location service, even if you don't have permissions.
5. If you do call the CLLocationManager you will start receiving location messages, after permissions have been granted to your app, without having to re-register to receive location messages.

Our solution:

The combination of 4 and 5 was our saving grace. We were faced with an edge case where a user could have been eligible for a location event trigger but previously had denied use the location services and then after becoming eligible the user grants us permission to use location services. After doing a little refactoring we moved our location manager so we would register for location event updates, specifically geofencing, even if we did not have permissions. After testing we found that in the edge case event we started receiving location updates even without having to reinitialize the location manager. The same applies to beacon region monitoring for anyone interested.

Answer (score 1):

Just check your location services after app has entered foreground.

```
  NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(applicationDidEnterForeground), name: UIApplication.didEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)

  func applicationDidEnterForeground() {
    print("Location services enabled? \(CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled())")
  }
```